# Can we do multi actions with js & html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a (simple) question : is it possible to do 2 differents actions when I click on a picture on an html page? Are there examples to explain that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the actions you want to do?

Comment: Short answer yes.  Long answer, first tell me what you want to do.

Comment: I want to do 2 actions : - Change my picture and do another action (specific with my application, it's just an instruction which is called : trigger)

Comment: Have a look at my answer below. Changing src of image and trigger other actions.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that's easy.

```
document.getElementById("myPic").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    doActionOne();
    doActionTwo();
});
```

Comment: Imagine you have two pictures and this is not the same actions if you click on picture 1 or on picture 2. Should I create 2 differents functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do simultaneous actions within an onclick event attached to your picture, using jQuery or plain javaScript.
In jQuery for instance, where #myImg is the id of the image:

HTML image tag:

```
<img id ="myImg" alt="image" src="someImg.png">
```

jQuery code:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

        (function ($) {
            $(window).load(function () {
                $("#myImg").click(function () {
                   //Change source of the image
                   $(this).attr( "src", "anotherimage.png" );
                    // Do something else here...
                });

            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

Using plain javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('myImg').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     //Change source of the image
      this.setAttribute('src', 'anotherimage.png');
     // Do something else here...
   });
 };
</script>
```

Comment: `language` attribute on script is deprecated.

Comment: You're correct. Damn copy/paste from old stuff! Edited my answer.